# Changing the material of the Hololens SpatialMapping prefab from Holotoolkit through script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, hololens, partial-classes

I am creating a project for the Microsoft Hololens through Unity3D, version 2017.4.16f1. I have the HoloToolkit added to my project, and am using its default SpatialMapping prefab. I am also using the HololensShaderPack found on the asset store and am using one of its provided shaders on the SpatialMapping prefab.

My application involves tapping on an object/surface to take a color from it and change the color of the spatial mesh's material's color to be the color you "stole" from that surface. The tapping works fine, as well as the color-grabbing. All I have to do is access the material found in the SpatialMappingManager script.

My problem is I am not sure how to access a member of a partial class, especially if that partial class is a singleton. I am not too familiar with this aspect of C# and have tried to find a solution online.

The SpatialMappingManager script is defined as follows, with irrelevant parts omitted:

```
namespace HoloToolkit.Unity.SpatialMapping
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(SpatialMappingObserver))]
    public partial class SpatialMappingManager : Singleton<SpatialMappingManager>
    {

        [Tooltip("The material to use for rendering spatial mapping data.")]
        [SerializeField]
        private Material surfaceMaterial;

        public Material SurfaceMaterial
        {
            get
            {
                return surfaceMaterial;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != surfaceMaterial)
                {
                    surfaceMaterial = value;
                    SetSurfaceMaterial(surfaceMaterial);
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetSurfaceMaterial(Material setSurfaceMaterial)
        {
            SurfaceMaterial = setSurfaceMaterial;
            if (DrawVisualMeshes)
            {
                foreach (MeshRenderer sourceRenderer in Source.GetMeshRenderers())
                {
                    if (sourceRenderer != null)
                    {
                        sourceRenderer.sharedMaterial = setSurfaceMaterial;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my other script, I am trying this:

```
public GameObject sm; //assigned in-editor
public SpatialMapping smm;

void Start()
{
    smm = sm.GetComponent<SpatialMapping>();
}

void ChangeColor(Color newColor) //this is called in an omitted part of the script that assigns newColor
{
    //what I WANT to do:
    Material newMat = smm.getSurfaceMaterial();
    newMat.color = newColor;
    smm.SetSurfaceMaterial(newMat);

}
```

However, it won't let me access these member variables/functions of the partial class. I also don't think Is it because it's a singleton, or am I unable to access members of a partial class like this? How else could I go about doing this?

Comment: In your other script, smm is a SpatialMapping object, not a SpatialMappingManager object.

Comment: Correct, however I am unable to create a SpatialMappingManager object. It does not recognize "SpatialMappingManager" as a possible class type. I was hoping there was some way to access the partial class through the SpatialMapping class instance.

Comment: Are you referencing the SpatialMappingManager through by using or specifying its namespace, HoloToolkit.Unity.SpatialMapping? I can't think of a reason it would be due to it being a singleton or partial class.

Comment: Also, since it's a singleton, you would probably use SpatialMappingManager.Instance instead of GetComponent.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, thank you for your comments. The confusion came from the fact that the HoloToolkit comes with a "SpatialMapping" prefab (with all SpatialMapping scripts on it), as well as a "SpatialMapping" class, as well as a "SpatialMapping" namespace. I was incorrectly creating a SpatialMapping class instance to try to access classes in the namespace, which are separate from the class.
I instead included the SpatialMapping namespace and set the SpatialMappingManager (smm) to SpatialMappingManager.Instance like you said. From there I was able to access its members.